# Is boost::make_shared obsolete now?

Tags: c++, boost

Is `boost::make_shared` obsolete now? Haven't found its definition in 1.35.

Comment: Ironically most people coming here now are probably wondering (like myself) if it is obsolete because it is in C++11. (Short answer: yes, you can use std:: versions.)

Comment: ...unless you need to keep compatibility to pre-C++11 platforms, in which case the Boost smart pointers are a *really* nice benefit.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Its in the 1.4 docs: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared.html

It appears to have been added in version 1.39

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Is there any way to find out which version it has been introduced?

Comment: The smart_ptr doc has a history section that may help you find what you need: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm#History

Comment: It was shown as part of how you do stuff now, instead of directly calling new, in the BUILD-windows talk here, but I assume it's std::make_shared now... http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-835T

Answer (score 30):

`std::make_shared` is also available in C++11. Please note that `make_shared` is more than just a convenience function. Take a look at the following code fragment:

```
make_shared<foobar>(1, 2);
shared_ptr<foobar>(new foobar(1, 2));
```

Both statements create a `foobar` object and construct a `shared_ptr`. However, the former avoids a memory allocation for the shared counter, because a single memory chunk will be used for the counter and the foobar object. This is not possible with the second statement, because the memory for `foobar` is allocated before the `shared_ptr` is constructed.

What I want to say: No, `make_shared` is not obsolete, because it provides a very useful optimization.

Comment: In C++11, ``std::make_shared`` is actually a performance optimization over creating an object, then creating the ``std::shared_ptr``, because it only performs one memory allocation instead of two.

Comment: Another important difference is thread safety. In the second example, `shared_ptr`' ctor may throw while foobar allocated by nested new will not be released.

Answer (score 3):

Did a bit of research today, and it seems that make_shared actually was added to 1.36.0 (in 1.35.0 there is no such header), but the interesting thing is that there is no single mention in What's new about this change - at least I could not find it